# How to make express routing work in electron

Tags: node.js, express, electron

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

    var hosSchemaModel = require('../schema.js')
    var path    = require("path")

// const app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
router.listen(port);

router.get('/requests/:_id', (req, res, next) =>    {
    console.log('Dynamic Link WORKS!!');
    hosSchemaModel.findOne({ _id: req.params._id }, function(err, request){
        res.json(request)
        // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'../homePage.html'))
    });
});

router.get('/all', (req, res) =>    {
    console.log('Dynamic Link WORKS!!');
    res.send('WORKS!!');
    // hosSchemaModel.findOne({ _id: req.params._id }, function(err, request){
    //  res.json(request)
    //  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'../homePage.html'))
    // });
});


 module.exports = router;

</script>
```

I tried to put it in the main process as well but it didn't work and I figured it should be implemented in the client-side. The routers doesn't work.

when I use `<a href="/all"` it takes me to an empty page and nothing is printed to the console

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This code is Node related and should be in a separated file. Let's call it `server.js`.
It should also load your static files and become your main server.

Then in the electron `main.js` file, you should require your express server and load:

```
const server = require('./server');

...

mainWindow.loadUrl('http://localhost:5000')
```

Complete example here: https://gist.github.com/maximilian-ruppert/a446a7ee87838a62099d